# UIView transform animations not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

Currently there is a view I'm trying to translate(move), rotate and scale a view at the same time.  For so strange reason it's only scaling it when I put scale at the bottom. But when I change the order and put the scaling first it rotates and translates the view properly but the scale of the view changes briefly to its correct scale before changing back to its original size. I need it to stay in it's scaled form.  Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


 let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.view.addSubview(newView)


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {


      self.newView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 70)//translation
      self.newView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)//rotation
      self.newView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 0.5)//scale
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combine the transforms first, then apply them at a time:

```
    let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 70)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.view.transform =  translate.rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi / 2).scaledBy(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    })
```

Comment: @SwiftyJD Also you should animate view in **viewWillAppear** method or other but you should not do it in **viewDidiLoad** method

Comment: @BalajiGalave, agree

Comment: I just tried your method, it's giving me errors: " Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' " for the  "CGAffineTransform translate" line

Comment: @SwiftyJD, let me test the code in IDE, please wait.

Comment: @YunCHEN I switched it to  var  translate: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 70) and it worked but for the  self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, rotate, scale) it throws the error:  Extra argument in call

Comment: @SwiftyJD, Sorry, I mixed the code between OC and swift. And now it's pure swift.

Comment: @YunCHEN I just tried the new swift code, its having the same issues I had with the original code where its only scaling but thats it.

Comment: @SwiftyJD, I have tested the transforms, they are working correctly: position moved (50,70), rotated -90 angle, height reduced 50%. What's your  issue?

Comment: @SwiftyJD, please set my answer as the accepted one if it's helped, thanks.